# Firefox not displaying login screen

Tags: 14.04, firefox, internet

My school uses Lightspeed Systems for internet, and when a new device connects to the internet, when try to access an internet service, it redirects to a login screen: `rs-lightspeed01.[schoolname].local`.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, however, when I connect to the internet and go to Google using Firefox, it redirects to the login page but displays 'Server not found'.

Despite this, it still does *not* fail when I ping the IP `74.125.224.72`.

How do I get onto the internet using Firefox?

### Edit:

Wget and the standard Ubuntu web browser fails on this too.

Comment: If it fails on all three, but succeeds via IP, you might need to look into your DNS settings. It is surprising that your school uses a non-private IP block for a `.local` domain. Can you see what DNS settings are set on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix [here](http://www.woofpuppy.com/2012/05/solving-local-dns-resolution-problems.html):

> In my testing, using the Avahi preferred solution of changing the mDNS domain to something else, I did indeed regain the ability to resolve .local hosts from my VPN, but I effectively lost use of all mDNS devices because (I presume) they weren't also changed to advertise in that same replacement local zone. With no idea how (or the interest, frankly) to try to reconfigure all of my other devices, so I decided to try option 2 and adjust the search order in /etc/nsswitch.conf. To do this:
>
> Edit /etc/nsswitch.conf and change the following line:
>
> ```
> hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
> ```
>
> And save your changes. Now, test ping one of your .local host names to verify the change has taken effect as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any other browser is able to browse to internet.

If your school network uses a proxy, then you need to add those proxy details in your network connection.

Comment: Could elaborate on this? How do I find and/or add the proxy details?

Comment: Also wget says 'unable to resolve host address [login address]'